# FutureBuilder does not get the updated data from the database

Tags: flutter

I'm using sqflite as my database and I access the data on the FutureBuilder, every time the app start I store the snapshot in a variable so that I can use it. The problem is when I go to another page and update the data, and when I go back to the page where I put the futurebuilder, the snapshot isn't updated therefore the variable where I store the snapshot data is also not being updated. Yet when I hot reload it will update.

This is the Future builder.

```
FutureBuilder<List<Place>>(
        future: dataBaseHelperPlace.getPlaceList(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Place>> snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            _places = snapshot.data;//this is where I store data.
```

This is where I update the database

```
onPressed: () {

  setState(() {
    if(isHearted){
      _user.heartPlace = _user.heartPlace.toString().replaceAll(fullPlaceID+"|",'');
      //print(_user.heartPlace);
      iconColors[0] = Colors.white;
      isHearted = false;
      _place.heartCount--;

    }
    else{
      _user.heartPlace = _user.heartPlace==null? '': _user.heartPlace;
      _user.heartPlace+=fullPlaceID+"|";
      //print( _user.heartPlace);
      iconColors[0] = ScubaBlue.withAlpha(255);
      isHearted = true;
      _place.heartCount++;

    }
    dataBaseHelperPlace.updatePlace(_place, _place);//This part is where the data is being updated
    dataBaseHelperUser.updateUser(_user);

  });
 
},),
```

I just want to update the variable where I store the snapshot data.

Comment: Is FutureBuilder called the second time when you go back from another page? I suspect that the function  dataBaseHelperPlace.getPlaceList() is not triggered.

Comment: I got it man, I just need to push the page where the futurebuilder is.